# ReactImageView: Image source "null" doesn't exist but in a node modules

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to make a development build of my app (producing in react native with expo), when I enter the dev build this error appears to me and doesn't render anything. this error is located inside the node modules of the "LogBox" library in react native (0.71.13)

Error:
 `WARN  ReactImageView: Image source "null" doesn't exist WARN  ReactImageView: Image source "null" doesn't exist WARN  ReactImageView: Image source "null" doesn't exist WARN  ReactImageView: Image source "null" doesn't exist WARN  ReactImageView: Image source "null" doesn't exist WARN  ReactImageView: Image source "null" doesn't exist WARN  ReactImageView: Image source "null" doesn't exist`

I already tried to check if the version of expo and react native are compatible and they are, so I don't know what to do.